# Electron: my custom config.json is not being loaded

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, electron, electron-builder

I'm new to Electron Framework. I'm adding my custom config.json in my project root and accessing it in a file **main.js**. This file is successfully be loaded when I execute project using npm start but when I create exe file using **electron-builder**, I get an error message:-

```
Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Rohaan Ishfaq\AppData\Local\Programs\examsoft_V0.20\config.json
```

Here is main.js file:-

```
// Module for creating child processes
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
// Module for path manipulations
const path = require('path');
// Module to create calls between windows
const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
// Module jQuery
const $ = require('jquery'); 
// Module for file manipulations
const fs = require('fs');
// config json
const config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('config.json', 'utf-8'));

(function main() {

    init();
    events();

    function init () {
        createSSHKey();
    }

    function events() {

        // get login btn by id
        const loginBtn = $('#login');
        // register event listener
        loginBtn.click(function (event) {
            ipc.send('change-to-login');
        });
    }

    function createSSHKey() {
        if(!fs.existsSync(config.utilsPath))
            alert(config.utilsPath + ' doesn\'t exist');
        else {
            var sshKeyPath = path.normalize(config.sshKeygenPath);
            //trigger .bat file
            ls = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', sshKeyPath]);

            //on data
            ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
                console.log('stdout: ' + data);
            });

            //on error
            ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
                alert('Error Occured: '+ data);
                process.exit(1);
            });

            //on exit
            ls.on('exit', function (code) {
                alert('SSH key pair has been created successfully. Check '+config.usersPath+process.env.USERNAME+config.sshDirectoryPath+' directory');
                enableLogin();
            });
        }
    }

    function enableLogin() {
        $('#login').text('Start');
        $('#login').prop('disabled', false);
    }

})();
```

Any one who has faced this kind of issue and fixed it successfully?

Answer (score 1):

Because your app is packed into [asar](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/application-packaging.md) archive. To access your files directly, please configure [extraFiles](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/wiki/Options#BuildMetadata-extraFiles) option.

Comment: Can you please give example of how to use extraFiles option?

Comment: e.g. `"extraResources": "**/config.json",` in the `build` (https://github.com/Quacky2200/Spotify-Web-Player-for-Linux/blob/master/package.json#L18).